# What can Gandalf do, and what can't he do to help?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, gandalf

From what I've read on these forums the race or type of being Gandalf is sort of god-like immortal, like the rest of the wizards. I think I remember reading that they can't interfere in some way.

What are the limitations of what Gandalf can and can't do to alter history?

Comment: Sidenote, you don't need to (and, I would say, *shouldn't*) delete questions that have been closed as duplicates. There's a reason the system puts the dupe question right at the top of the page: even if they won't have an answer on the page, they're useful signposts for future travellers

Comment: @JasonBaker I guess leaving them would allow people to find these answers faster in the future. I understand I don't need to, but do you think it would be more beneficial to delete?

Comment: It's ultimately your decision, but I wouldn't. You never know what people are going to search for (either on SE's search, or on Google), so having more paths to the correct answer is always a good thing